C++ GUI DateTimePicker date value to TextBox
I have a TextBox and a DateTimePicker and I want the selected date in the DateTimePicker to be written in the TextBox.
In short what do I need to write inside here?
private: System::Void Date_Text_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}

The above code is for the TextBox that I want to inherit the string from the DateTimePicker. And the one below is for the DateTimePicker itself.
private: System::Void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}

I tried so many things but no matter what I did I could not make Text-> which is the command to place text in the TextBox accept anything related to the DateTimePicker.

The first event (Date_Text_TextChanged) does not seem relevant. It is triggered when the context of the TextBox itself changes, and you are would like to monitor changes in the DateTimePicker.
For that the second event (dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged) is the relevant one.
In order to update the TextBox when the user selects a date in the DateTimePicker, you need to modify it as following:
System::Void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    // This assume the name of your `TextBox` is `Date_Text`, 
    // modify it if needed:
    Date_Text->Text = dateTimePicker1->Value->ToString();
}

Note that the Value property of the DateTimePicker is of type DateTime, and it supports various string representation formats that you can pass as argument to ToString(). You can see more info about it here: Custom date and time format strings.

You can use standard databindings to bind the Value property of a DateTimePicker to, in this case, the Text property of a TextBox. No need to subscribe to any event.
Add this to stdafx.h (or another include file you use for the same purpose):
#pragma once
#define nameof(_propname) #_propname

In the Form's Constructor (assuming the name assigned to the TextBox is Date_Text):
Date_Text->DataBindings->Add(
    nameof(Text), 
    dateTimePicker1, 
    nameof(Value), 
    true, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode::OnPropertyChanged
);

Formatting is set to true, you have the same representation of, e.g., DateTime::Now.ToString(), using the current System::Globalization::CultureInfo
